# Jprofilerti.dll 9.0.3 Crashes as App starts doing it major purposes

Tags: networking, dll, crash, jprofiler

An Eclipse RCP application crashes in the jprofilerti.dll code once I move the app from relatively idle status to full operation.

Some initial profile results are available back on the remote GUI session. This suggests that the configuration of Jprofiler GUI, Jprofiler agent, and network settings is ok.

I wonder if the crash occurs due to buffer overruns. I ask because the network link between the remote JVM and the near laptop JProfiler GUI is very poor with a very low effective bit rate. Is it possible that the target JVM will crash if the remote GUI is too slow about consuming buffered profiling data?

Comment: Do you have any non-standard VM parameters like -XX:+UseParNewGC or -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC in your Java invocation? Those can crash the profiling interface. If not, please send the crash log (hserr_pid...) to support@ej-technologies.com

Comment: Rather, I believe it is because the target JVM is 64-bit Windows jdk8 and is not yet supported by the JProfiler DLL. If this is likely, can you suggest when Java 8 on Windows 64-bit will be supported?

Comment: 64-bit is supported, it has a different DLL. In the bin directory of the JProfiler installation there are different 32-bit and 64-bit directories for all platforms.